# youtube embeded objects ie9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, youtube-api

A friend and I are writing a c# application that generates HTML pages, we've run into a problem when trying to embed YouTube videos in that page, on my computer it runs and plays fine, but on his it doesn't display. his flash seems to be up to date, and he's been able to replicate the issue on another computer, but I have been unable to replicate it at all.

He can go to YouTube and play videos directly off the website, but running any embedded videos on another site will result in failure, we've tried copying the code it spits out making our own HTML file and playing it from there, and that works fine for me, but not for him.

```
    <object style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Cr-SqRWImmI?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&feature=player_embedded">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Cr-SqRWImmI?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&feature=player_embedded" 
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="100%" height="100%">
    </object>
```

edit: c# isn't relevant to the problem. html youtube embeded videos don't display in ie9 on my friends computer. i removed the tag and replaced it with an html tag.

edit2: i really don't know why someone would downvote me on this question, but i provided a solution so if someone who has the same problem comes across it, rather than deleting the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the javascript api to embed the video and access the controls and we used swfobject.js. Once we switched to that method the rendered output worked in ie on my friend's machine.

edit: here is the code sample.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>    
<div id="player">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "player" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/Cr-SqRWImmI?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&playerapiid=player&feature=player_embedded",
                   "player", "100%", "100%", "8", null, null, params, atts);

</script>
```